# Load more than one video on a webpage using the iOS platform

Tags: ios, html, html5-video, touch-event, autoplay

I have a webpage with four VIDEO elements. I know that they elements won't even start loading any metadata until I explicitly trigger a touch event on them. Can I hook up an event handling function on the touch event on, say, a BUTTON element such that the "play" methods on all four VIDEO elements are invoked?

I mean something along these lines:

```
$b1.bind("touchstart", function (e) {
    $v1.get(0).play();
    $v1.get(0).pause();
    $v2.get(0).play();
    $v2.get(0).pause();
    $v3.get(0).play();
    $v3.get(0).pause();
    $v4.get(0).play();
    $v4.get(0).pause();
});
```

When I try this four separate QuickTime windows are opened with fullscreen videos. That's not the effect I want, but at least I can hook all four to the handler. The problem, though, is that only $v4 actually starts loading anything, and the other three apparently never start loading.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot start multiple videos at once. Every time you start a video on iOS, the currently running video will be stopped. This is a performance restriction on all mobile apple devices. For the same reason the `preload` attribute has no relevance on current iOS devices.

I'm guessing you want the videos to be inline? then add `webkit-playsinline` as an attribute to each `<video>` element:

`<video src="myvideo.mp4" webkit-playsinline controls>`

that way you can arrange the 4 video-elements next to each other AND use native video-controls (e.g. to allow switching to native fullscreen later). If you want to implement your own controls leave out the `controls` attribute.

PS: following up on 0x60's link, you *can* find a section called [iOS-Specific Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1)

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html) out? Set your code to: `<video preload="automatic" />` and it should preload.

Comment: sorry but thats for Safari-Desktop only.